# While formatting a float number using System.out.format(), irrelevant answers are shown up. Why?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain how my below code was interpreted.

```
float n = 534343434.66f;
System.out.printf("%13.3f",n);
```

Output:

```
534343424.000
```

Why this output?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Float` size in Java is 4 bytes.
So, use `double` instead using `float`.

```
double n = 534343434.66;
System.out.printf("%13.3f",n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your n variable contains `float` value instead `double` as you have appended f at the end

```
double n = 534343434.66;
System.out.printf("%.2f\n",n);
```

result: 534343434.66